# Анимация проигрывается только 1 раз

Tags: c#, unity3d, augmented-reality

я использую Unity 2020.2.6f1, и мне нужно сделать так, что-бы пока мое приложение было включено, анимация на объекте проигрывалась, но к сожалению при запуске моего приложения анимация проигрывается только 1 раз, в чем может быть причина? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если тебе нужно проигрывать одну анимацию без связей и других анимаций, то делай так:

1. Удаляй компонент `Animator` со своего объекта
2. Добавь компонент `Animation`
3. Открой окно анимации (Ctrl+6)
4. Настрой анимацию для объекта
5. В компоненте `Animation` закинь в ячейку Animation свой клип
6. Нажми на сам клип и включи там `Loop`

Главное, чтобы анимация была создана с компонентом `Animation` на объекте, т.к. анимация с аниматора имеет другой набор свойств

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй просто прописать зацикленую функцию старта анимации если анимация не проигрываеться(не уверен насколько это правильно, но работать будет)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("name"))
        {
            StartAnim();
        }
    }

    private void StartAnim()
    {
        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("name");
    }
}
```

Comment: И Вам спасибо за готовность помочь!:)